# why does the commit error in vb.net sendkeys to ESC?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hi i am doing a datagriview and when there is a commit error in one of the cells for example if you are editing and leave a cell empty you will fire the commit error. The cell will  value will change to its original. I want to force users to enter the value instead of undoing it.
Is there a way to change commit error structure

here is the coding for datagridview error for commit error

```
           If (e.Context = DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) _
           Then

        MessageBox.Show("Do not leave the cells empty ")


         End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not sendkeys to ESC, but it's not validated .. so the cell will replaced by the old value

In your datagridview validating event add this

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Validating( .... ) Handler ....

    e.Cancel = False

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried that and its not really working i added the coding would you check it out?